# How can I populate an array containing ObjectId as elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a favorite.js model in which dishes is a array of ObjectId's. I was able to populate the user(also contains ObjectId) with its data but I can't manage to do the same for dishes as there is no object in the array.

```
const favoriteSchema = new Schema({
user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
dishes: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
},{
timestamps: true
})
var Favorite = mongoose.model('Favorite',favoriteSchema)
module.exports = Favorite
```

I tried populating the dishes array but it returned an error saying incorrect path.

```
favoriteRouter.route('/')
.get(authenticate.verifyUser,(req,res,next)=>{
Favorites.findOne({"user":req.user._id})
.populate('dishes')
.populate('user')
.then((favorite)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
    res.setStatus = 200
    res.json(favorite)
})
.catch((err)=>{
    next(err);
})
}
```

I want the output to be as follows..

Before Population:

```
{
"dishes": [
    "5e2c30b910e3ff15d85ffd7e",
    "dnj4k60d1822785e2d5c603"
],
"_id": "5e2d5c6032f0a60d182d971c",
"user": "5e2d5c603dnj4k60d182278v",
"createdAt": "2020-01-26T09:31:12.267Z",
"updatedAt": "2020-01-26T09:31:13.021Z",
"__v": 1
}
```

After Population:

```
{
"dishes": [
    {
      //populated content as object
       },
    {
      //populated content as object
       }
],
"_id": "5e2d5c6032f0a60d182d971c",
"user": {
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "admin": true,
    "_id": "5e289e47d48a6016ec233078",
    "username": "admin",
    "__v": 0
},
"createdAt": "2020-01-26T09:31:12.267Z",
"updatedAt": "2020-01-26T09:31:13.021Z",
"__v": 1
}
```

Comment: You'll need to create a `dishes` schema and have a reference to its model in `favoriteSchema` as `dishes: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Dishes"}]`

Comment: But I need a array of objectsID not a array of objects. Your solution will result in a array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to populate an array of ObjectId's.

```
favoriteRouter.route('/')
.get(authenticate.verifyUser,(req,res,next)=>{
Favorites.findOne({"user":req.user._id})
.populate('user')
.populate({        //Populating the dishes
    path:'dishes',
    model:'Dish'
})
.then((favorite)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
    res.setStatus = 200
    res.json(favorite)
})
.catch((err)=>{
    next(err);
})
})
```